# how to find comma separated values from mysql table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables. I joined both table.

In controller:

```
$data = array();
$distinct_unique_id_for_group = circulateFile::select('unique_id_for_group')->distinct()->get();
  foreach($distinct_unique_id_for_group as $distinct)
  {  
   $data[] = DB::table('circulate_files')
                    ->join('regionmasters','circulate_files.region_id','=','regionmasters.id')
                    ->where('circulate_files.unique_id_for_group','=',$distinct->unique_id_for_group)
                    ->select('circulate_files.*','regionmasters.region')
                    ->get();
        }
```

In above query,  In circulateFiles table I have a column **unique_id_for_group**. I have to get rows with the help of **unique_id_for_group**

and I got this type of array in view:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
        (
            [items:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [title] => title1
                            [region] => east
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [title] => title1
                            [region] => west
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
        (
            [items:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [title] => title2
                            [region] => east
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [title] => title2
                            [region] => south
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need output like this:

```
  REGION           | TITLE
 
   east, west      | title1  
   east, south     | title2
```

Means region should be in comma separated value and title is same, so title should be unique.

I tried by this:

```
 @foreach($data as $arraydata)
   <tr>
    <td>{{ $arraydata->region }}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

I am not getting idea how to do that?

Comment: show your query, which you are using for this collection?

Comment: Kindly check my question. I updated this.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

```
$data = DB::table('circulate_files')
                    ->join('regionmasters','circulate_files.region_id','=','regionmasters.id')
                    ->select('circulate_files.title','circulate_files.file','circulate_files.created_at','unique_id_for_group', DB::raw('group_concat(region) as new_region'))
                    ->groupBy('unique_id_for_group')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the Following code:**

```
$data = DB::table('circulate_files')
       ->selectRaw('circulate_files.title, unique_id_for_group, 
            group_concat(region) as new_region
        ')
        ->join('regionmasters', 'circulate_files.region_id', 'regionmasters.id')
        ->groupBy('unique_id_for_group')
        ->get();
```